# Could somebody explain why exactly is the density of the lower rod is equal to $f(g(u))$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, jacobian

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCZ1VEmVjVo) about the Jacobian, the youtuber explains the concept of the Jacobian as well as integration. Around the 18th minute, he gives an example of two one-dimensional rods. One with endpoints $(a,b)$, the other one with $(g(a),g(b))$. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Could somebody explain why exactly is the density of the lower rod equal to $f(g(u))$? For me it's not clear how $f$ and $g$ are connected so that the density of the lower rod equals $f(g(u))$.

Comment: Try seeing how a small length is mapped in under g

Comment: There is some assumptions about the physical nature of the road being made I think

Comment: A point on the second rod (position $u$) maps to position $g(u)$ on the original rod. The density of the original rod is a function of its position and at position $x$, the density is $f(x)$. In this case, $x = g(u)$. So density given as $f(x)$ can be written as $f(g(u))$

Comment: @Buraian I just checked and I am not sure if such a property exists. Will see if I can find something.

Comment: Did the question make sense as I had written it @MathLover? repost: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662162/name-of-property-where-density-function-after-thermal-expansion-is-related-to-th

Comment: @Buraian Yes it did make sense to me. As I am not part of Physics community I could not comment there :) May be you can link your below answer to say that in some sense you are trying to find real life example of it?

Comment: Yes , done @MathLover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The density of the lower rod at point $u$ is NOT $f(g(u))$. It is $f(g(u))\cdot |g'(u)|$ as explained a few moments later (it has absolute values since we're talking about densities). So, the youtuber's explanation around the 18.45 minute mark that the two segments have "same density but different lengths" is incorrect and misleading. It should say "same mass but not necessarily same lengths", and hence not necessarily same densities (which is ultimately what they arrive at, but I think there's a good 30s of confusion in the middle of the explanation).

Actually, I've already written an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4178774/568204) about a very similar question. I think the first half of that answer is relatively understandable because I restricted myself to use very few formulas; the second half of the answer is more technical (because OP asked how things generalize, so I gave the details there) so you can skip that if you wish.

Anyway, I'll try to rephrase the argument restricting to the 1-dimensional case. So, we consider two rods, and a function $g:L\to U$, which maps the lower rod onto the upper rod. For the sake of intuition, you may want to assume $g$ is bijective (i.e invertible); and to visualize things you may want to think of the rods as being an elastic material, so that the function $g$ either stretches/squishes parts of the rods in a certain fashion; so it is something which deforms the original rod.

Let us suppose that the upper rod has a density function $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$, and assume it's nice and continuous, and that the lower rod has continuous density function $\rho:L\to\Bbb{R}$. Also, suppose $g$ is $C^1$. Our task is to find the relationship between $f,g,\rho$. Now consider a point $u\in L$ on the lower rod, and a small interval $[u,u+\delta]$ containing the point $u$. Note that the function $g$ since we're thinking of it merely as a continuous deformation, it had better conserve the mass, meaning:
\begin{align}
&\text{mass of the segment $[u,u+\delta]$ of lower rod}\\
&= \text{mass of the deformed segment $g([u,u+\delta])$ in the upper rod}
\end{align}

Suppose $\delta>0$ is very small. Then, by continuity of $\rho$, it follows that the density of the lower rod at each point of the segment $[u,u+\delta]$ is approximately $\rho(u)$. So, the LHS of the equation above is approximately $\rho(u)\cdot \text{length of the interval $[u,u+\delta]$}$

Next, since we assumed $g$ to be continuous, it follows that the deformed interval $g([u,u+\delta])$ will also be a small interval containing the point $g(u)$. Thus, the density function $f$ is approximately constant here with value $f(g(u))$. So, the mass of this rod is approximately $f(g(u))\cdot \text{length of $g([u,u+\delta])$}$. Thus, plugging in these approximations to the equation above we get
\begin{align}
\rho(u)\cdot \text{length of $[u,u+\delta]$} &\approx f(g(u))\cdot \text{length of $g([u,u+\delta])$}
\end{align}
Thus, rearranging,
\begin{align}
\rho(u)&\approx f(g(u))\cdot \frac{\text{length of $g([u,u+\delta])$}}{\text{length of $[u,u+\delta]$}}
\end{align}
As we let $\delta\to 0^+$, it is highly likely that the RHS approaches $f(g(u))\cdot |g'(u)|$ (the absolute values are there since we're talking about ratios of lengths; if I had merely written $\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0^+}\frac{g(u+\delta)-g(u)}{\delta}$, then this would indeed be $g'(u)$).

Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
\rho(u)&=f(g(u))\cdot |g'(u)|
\end{align}
In other words,
\begin{align}
\text{density of lower rod at point $u$}&=
(\text{density of upper rod at point $g(u)$})\\
& \times (\text{limit of ratio of lengths due to the mapping $g$, at point $u$})
\end{align}
This last formula extends verbatim in logic to any number of dimensions (as I explained in my linked answer; simply replace "length" in this equation by "$n$-dimensional volume")

---

Finally, a word of caution. What this answer tells you is the **heuristics** (very valuable one) for the change of variables formula. This reasoning is definitely not a *proof*, but it's a good indication of how one might arrive at the correct formula (in the one-dimensional case if we assume $f$ is continuous and $g$ is $C^1$ then the proof is a triviality using the FTC, but in higher dimensions this is a **VERY** non-trivial theorem to prove correctly).

Comment: Thus, the density function f is approximately constant here with value f(g(u)).... this is exactly the point I don't get.. what is the name of this approximation? Is it neccesarily truefor real life rods?

Comment: @Buraian The reason is continuity. Continuity of $g$ implies $g([u,u+\delta])$ is a "small interval" containing the point $g(u)$. Next, since we assume $f$ is continuous, it's values over a small interval doesn't change much (this is almost the definition of continuity). That's why the density is approximately constant with value $f(g(u))$ there (which is precisely what I said in my answer). If you want to make this precise, write out the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: As for whether it's true for rods in real life, I'd say under normal circumstances it is a very good assumption. I mean take a look at spoons in your house, or take a look at lamps, or any type of metallic ring you may have/ metallic pens etc etc. Surely you'd agree with me that their mass distribution is 'continuous' in some sense. It's not like there's a jump discontinuity or any other such pathology. Realistically speaking, you'll probably not notice a significant expansion when you heat things at everyday temperatures).

Comment: I'm having a real difficulty trying to explain it properly. Let me try: Just like in the physics post , we are saying there is map (old rod length-> new rod length-> density of old rod), or the new rod's density is obtained by composing the old one's density by the map of the points. There are many ways to map points on the first rod to the second rod... exactly, what is the name of the physical property of the map, which makes it so density is just f'(g) g' ..?

Comment: I really don't think continuity is the exact name for this... maybe related but I don't think it is what it is. Maybe I am missing somethig.. I'll try thinking more

Comment: I mean you could say it is the pull-back of the density on the upper rod to the lower rod. If $f\,dl$ is the density on the upper rod then its pull back is $g^*(f\,dl)=(f\circ g)\cdot|g'|\,dl$ (I'm using $dl$ because I don't want to mix up densities and differential forms). In this answer, I wasn't trying to give names to things; I was trying to explain the reason for why the formula ought to be the way it is, and for this the *reason* is continuity.

Comment: Thanks. I only commented due to the comment you had put in physicsSE post. Mathematically, I think this is the superior answer and I have upvoted it myself as well.

Comment: (I deleted that comment since it doesn't seem logical to have the same conversation over 2 sites)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I'll try initially we have $x \in \left[ a, b \right]$ then we use the function $g(t)$ with $t \in \left[ g^{-1}(a), g^{-}(b)\right]$. Consider a segment with length $\Delta x$, the segment gets mapped to another segment $\Delta g$ under the action of $g$. Supposing the segment start at $x$ in the original rod:

$$ f(x) \Delta x = f(g(t) ) \Delta g$$

Integrating both sides from on the set $x= \left[a,b \right]$ and writing $\frac{\Delta g}{\Delta t} \Delta t = \Delta g$

$$ \int_{x=a}^{x=b} f(x) dx = \int_{x=a}^{x=b} f\left( g(t) \right) g'(t) dt \tag{1}$$

We need to change the bounds on RHS in terms of $t$:

$$\int_{x=a}^{x=b} f\left( g(t) \right) g'(t) dt = \int_{t=g^{-1}(a)}^{t=g^{-1}(b) } f(g(t) ) g'(t) dt \tag{2}$$

Combining (1) and (2), we get the required.

Comment: There are some assumptions about the density function which may not be true for real life.. I'll try figure it out and answer later

Comment: [Related Q I had asked on physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662162/name-of-property-where-density-function-after-thermal-expansion-is-related-to-th)... on the difficulties in trying to translate this into reality