# Why do we need Jacobian for change of variables in integration? Why do not we change variables in a straightforward way?

Tags: coordinate-systems, integration, calculus

I know that Jacobian is necessary to change the area element in integration, for example,
\begin{equation}
\Delta A= dx dy= \left|\frac{\partial x,\partial y}{\partial r ,\partial \theta}\right| drd\theta
\end{equation}
But why is the following thing is an illegal move,($x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$),
$$dx=dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta, dy=dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta$$
And so, $$\Delta A= dx dy= \left(dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta\right)\left(dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta\right)$$

Why the last equation is wrong ? If it is not wrong then, how is it connected to the first equation?

Comment: how would you integrate with $d\theta d\theta$? or with  $drdr$?

Comment: @hyportnex In math, you don’t just discard terms because you don’t know what to do with them.

Comment: @Ghoster exactly, hence the question.

Comment: It is wrong because the $dx,dy,dr,d\theta$ are not real numbers. So, if they're not real numbers, then there's no reason whatsoever to expect that you can multiply them like they're real numbers. Just because things miraculously worked out in single variable calculus gives one no right to assume that they will keep working out. See [Why is this derivation of the transformation from Cartesian to polar coordinates not correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3275058/568204) and [Polar Coordinate Transformation - Motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3628070/568204), and the other dupes.

Comment: For more 'intuitive' descriptions involving mass and density, take a look at [Could somebody explain why exactly is the density of the lower rod is equal to $f(g(u))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4236551/568204) and at a slightly more advanced level (though the first half should still be understandable), see [Behaviour of density function when flattening the hemisphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4178774/568204).

Comment: Thank you @peek-a-boo, I understand now. The answer that you gave in the shared link is very nice. Thanks a lot. :)